# How to add spaces upto a fixed column before a certain character in the line

Tags: regular-expression

Suppose I have a line in which the dot appears. Then, I want to add spaces upto fixed number of columns to indent my code. Also, I can't install plug in. Is there any way I can do with just command line?

Comment: Welcome to this website. For now your question is quite unclear and will need some precision to attract answers which will fit your needs. 1) Why did you mention a line in which the dot appears: Do you want to do something specific on this line? 2) Can you give a short example of a file you'd want to change and the result you expect? 3) Are you aware of the `=` command which is used to indent your code [`:h =`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3d)?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Please [edit] to add the requested information^